# Не удается выполнить PUT запрос

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework, rest

Всем привет.
На беке делаю PUT запрос для обновления данных в таблице.
Но получаю исключение в котором говорится, что  подразумевается изменение 1 значение, но изменено 0 значений.

Контроллер:

```
  [HttpPut("[action]")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<Result<BlackListEntity>> UpdateBlackListItem([FromBody] CreateItemBlackListCommand vm)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new UpdateItemBlackListCommand
        {
            ItemId = vm.ItemId,
            LastName = vm.LastName,
            FirstName = vm.FirstName,
            MiddleName = vm.MiddleName,
            CreateDate = vm.CreateDate,
            PhoneNumber = vm.PhoneNumber
        });
    }
```

Handler из Mediatr:

```
public Task<Result<BlackListEntity>> Handle(UpdateItemBlackListCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = _repository.UpdateAsync(new BlackListEntity()
        {
            CreateDate = request.CreateDate,
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            MiddleName = request.MiddleName,
            PhoneNumber = request.PhoneNumber,
            Status = request.Status

        }, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
```

Метод UpdateAsync из репозитория :

```
 async Task<Result<T>> IRepository<T>.UpdateAsync(T entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool updateNullValues, string? include)
    {
        try
        {

            var dbEntityEntry = this.Context.Attach(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

            if (await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) > 0)
            {
                this.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
                return Result.Ok(entity);
            }

            return Result.Fail<T>("Error while saving entity");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Logger.LogError(e, "Error while saving entity");
            return Result.Fail<T>("Exception while saving entity: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

И запрос в постмане:

```
{
    "ItemId": "aee10cf2-5370-4c84-9c4d-df2b95b7c517",
    "LastName": "LastName111",
    "FirstName": "vm.FirstName11111",
    "MiddleName": "vm.MiddleName11111",
    "PhoneNumber": "889900",
    "CreateDate": "2013-01-07T00:00:00Z"
```

}

Данные для запроса взял целиком из Get запроса с полуяением списка из базы, значение основных полей изменил, кроме ID.
И при отправлке ошибка :
""The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
"

пАмагИтИ :)

Comment: `ItemId = new Guid(),` - это что? Задаётся новый гуид. Естественно, сущности с таким id в БД нет. / Хотя, впрочем, в хендлере для BlackListEntity вообще не задаётся id.

Comment: Моя ошибка.  эти свойства копировал из метода CrateItemBlackList, который создает элемент. И не убрал ID. 
Поправил, но и без этого ID проблема сохраняется

Comment: Если вы поправили код, исправьте его в посте. И не видно, где вы передаете id существующей записи, или хотите создать новую?

Comment: Поправил :)
Так в JSON запросе первой строкой идет ID существующей записи.
И ниже измененные поля. 
Или надо как-то иначе оформлять запрос на обновление данных ?

Comment: Вы знаете, чем PUT от POST отличается? Вот туда и копать.

Comment: Ну +\- знаю разница. POST создает запись и создает ID, PUT по ID удаляет запись и перезаписывает. По написанию контроллера они вроде как не отличаются и там и там и передаю некий обхект с ID.
Я поправил на POST, интереса ради, и опять ловлю то же исключение *_*

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Все таки моя главная проблема - невнимательность. Только сегодня увидел как вы допсиали свой комментарий. Дейтсивтельно , я в хендлере забыл ID прописать. Спасибо. Теперь все работает :)